# How to import csv file to DB with asp.net mvc using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv, import

Sorry for this question as I'm new to asp.net. I need to make Import Csv files into  database that is made in sql server and added to web application by entity framework. I managed to export it, but have no clue how to import it other than maybe using StreamReader with regex. Tried using Lumenworks csvreader, but it doesn't cooparate with entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/) NuGet package. You can find parts of the code you need to use [here](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2014/03/18/seeding-entity-framework-database-from-csv.aspx).

Relevant code:

```
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
        csvReader.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
        var countries = csvReader.GetRecords<Country>().ToArray();
        context.Countries.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Code, countries);
 }
```